# Qualified-id in declaration before '=' token

Tags: c++, opencv, static, declaration

I have two public classes; one static (`DesktopOps`), one non-static (`Args`), and I'm trying to initialise the static variables of the static class in main.

The error message I keep getting is:

```
main.cpp:25: error: qualified-id in declaration before '=' token
     Point DesktopOps::window_coords = Point(arg.topleft_x, arg.topleft_y);
                                     ^
main.cpp:26: error: qualified-id in declaration before '=' token
     Point DesktopOps::window_dims = Point(arg.width, arg.height);
                                   ^
```

Here's a MWE:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

struct Args{
    int topleft_x, topleft_y, width, height;

    Args(){
        topleft_x = topleft_y = width = height = -1;
    }
};


struct DesktopOps {
    static Point window_coords;
    static Point window_dims;

};



int main(){
    Args arg();

    Point DesktopOps::window_coords = Point(arg.topleft_x, arg.topleft_y);
    Point DesktopOps::window_dims = Point(arg.width, arg.height);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do....but static variables must be created in global scope, outside the main function:

```
Args arg;
Point DesktopOps::window_coords = Point(arg.topleft_x, arg.topleft_y);
Point DesktopOps::window_dims = Point(arg.width, arg.height);

int main(){

}
```

But this global Args variable does not make sense....

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not knowing that static must be declared globally (how else will all members see it, doy), but what variable doesn't make sense? (I deleted a lot of intermediate code btw)

Comment: I mean that having to declare a global Args variable using default ctor just to use the members in static window_coords and window_dims initialization just fixes your compilation bug but is a very ugly way to do it....I'm prettry sure you'll arrange your code better.

Comment: well... here's the thing, Arg acually takes as `(int argc, char arv ***)` as arguments, so it does need to be within main.... but I'll figure  something out

Comment: You may just create `DesktopOps::window_coords` and `DesktopOps::window_dims` as `Point(0,0);` and modify them in your first lines of main. `static` does not mean `const`....

Comment: no wait... removing the `Point` type prefix the second time around solved the problem. I was redeclaring the same damn variables...once again I have failed at life itself

Comment: It should work. Within `main` function, `DesktopOps::window_coords.x = 3` for instance must modify the static variable.

Comment: OK, good to know your problem is fixed now. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 10):

In the structure you *declare* the member variables, but when you *define* them you can't do it in a function, it has to be done in the global scope, like

```
struct DesktopOps {
    static Point window_coords;
    static Point window_dims;
};

Point DesktopOps::window_coords = Point(someX, someY);
Point DesktopOps::window_dims = Point(someW, someH);

int main()
{
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately this can't be done since the initialization depends on the local `arg` variable in the `main` function. This means you have to do the definition and the initialization in two steps:

```
struct DesktopOps {
    static Point window_coords;
    static Point window_dims;
};

Point DesktopOps::window_coords;
Point DesktopOps::window_dims;

int main()
{
    Args arg;

    DesktopOps::window_coords = Point(arg.topleft_x, arg.topleft_y);
    DesktopOps::window_dims = Point(arg.width, arg.height);
}
```

---

Since the C++17 standard, `inline` member variable definitions is now available:

```
struct DesktopOps {
    inline static Point window_coords = Point(someX, someY);
    inline static Point window_dims = Point(someW, someH);
};
```

Comment: wow, left to make a sandwich and came back with a concise and informative solution. I understand now, though I don't get why this is necessary; i.e. why doesn't the compiler just do this for me?

Comment: Isn't that `Arg arg()` a function declaration?

Comment: it's the constructor initialised to variable `arg`, no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work @tetris11

Comment: Holy... I've never looked at it like that before, it really could be a function declaration! It doesn't flag errors though, but okay no more sloppy initializations